# Разница между @FindBy и findElements

Tags: java, selenium

В тесте использовала pageObject, однако

```
@FindBy("//...")
List<WebElement> options();
...
options().stram()...
```

возвращал пустой спискок.
Тот же самый xpath

```
List<WebElement> options = findElements(By.xpath("//..."));
```

возвращает три элемента.
Пыталась искать, почему так, однако нашла только объяснение, что по сути это одно и тоже; было одно упоминание, что @FindBy - динамический, а findElements() - статический, однако страница, на которой идёт работа, никак не меняется в процессе выполнения метода. В чём кардинальное различие в работе @FindBy и findElements(), что они могу возвращать разные значения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разница между `@FindBy` и `findElements` в том, что первый используется для разметки полей, которые связываются с элементами на странице после того как Вы воспользуетесь методом `PageFactory.init(...)`. В этот момент они инициализируются прокси-объектами и лукап элемента происходит только после фактического обращения к полю. В этом процессе замешаны механизмы рефлексии языка Java.

Всё это используется при реализации паттерна проектирования, называемого `page object`. Чуть подробнее можно почитать [здесь](https://webelement.click/ru/pagefactory_relative_lookup_java).

Метод `findElements` это просто инструкция для вебдрайвера найти на странице элемент по локатору. Этот поиск происходит в момент исполнения инструкции (она, кстати используется "под капотом", когда Вы обращаетесь к полю аннотированному `@FindBy`).

Разницы, по идее, быть не должно, если страница статическая. Может иметь значение контекст поиска (`SearchContext`) потому как, Вы можете искать как начиная от корня, так и начиная от уже обнаруженного элемента, но в Вашем случае это не должно влиять, потому как Вы используете xpath, начинающийся с `//`, который игнорирует контекст поиска.

Может также иметь значение стратегия кеширования (но она по умолчанию отключена). Если кеширование включено (при варианте с `@FindBy`), то последующие обращения к полю, не будут приводить к попытке нового поиска. Они будут вовзращать то, что было найдено при первом обращении к полю. В то время как `findElements` всегда будет искать элементы заново.

P.S. - Аннотация `@FindBy` должна использоваться в таком виде:

```java
@FindBy(xpath="//...")
List<WebElement> name;
```

У Вас в примере написано что-то странное. Наверное по памяти писали, потому что так оно и не скомпилируется.

Comment: на проектах, на которых была я, чаще всего использовали @FindBy("//..."), реже @FindBy(value = "//..."), и это работает. Контекст не менялся, однако проблема возникла, когда изначальный options() начал собирать все подходящие элементы на странице, игнорируя контекст